# MySQL JOIN with multiple tables and SUMS

Tags: mysql, join, sum

I am trying to create a query that will take information out of four tables for a billing system that I am creating. I have the following tables:

Table Invoice

```
InvoiceID (PK)
ClientID
Date
Status
...
```

Table Client

```
ClientID (PK)
ClientName
...
```

Table InvoiceItem

```
ItemID (PK)
InvoiceID
Amount
...
```

Table Payments

```
PaymentID (PK)
InvoiceID
Amount
...
```

I need to create a query where I can access information from the Invoice table along with the client name, and the sum of all invoice items and payments associated with the invoice.

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT 
    Invoice.InvoiceID, 
    Invoice.`Date`, 
    Invoice.Terms, 
    Invoice.DateDue, 
    Invoice.Status, 
    Client.ClinicName, 
    SUM(InvoiceItem.Amount), 
    SUM(Payment.PaymentAmount)
FROM Invoice
JOIN (Client, InvoiceItem, Payment) ON
    (Client.ClientID=Invoice.ClientID AND
     InvoiceItem.InvoiceID=Invoice.InvoiceID AND 
     Payment.InvoiceID=Invoice.InvoiceID)
```

And while this kind-of works, it is multiplying the SUM() by the number of records used to get the sum (i.e. if there are two payments - 800,400 - It gives me (800+400)*2 -- 2400). I am guessing that there is something with how I am using the join, and I have honestly never had to use join for more than one table, and I would always use GROUP BY, but I can't seem to get that to work correctly.

To make matters worse, I have been lost to the world of vb.net/MSSQL client-side programming for the past several years, so my MySQL is rather rough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that you can't aggregate over two independent tables at once in a single query. However you can do it using subqueries.

```
SELECT Invoice.InvoiceID, Invoice.`Date`, Invoice.Terms, Invoice.DateDue, Invoice.Status, Client.ClinicName, InvoiceItemSum.SumOfAmount, PaymentSum.SumOfPaymentAmount
  FROM Invoice
  INNER JOIN Client ON Client.ClientID = Invoice.ClientID
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT InvoiceID, SUM(Amount) AS SumOfAmount
      FROM InvoiceItem
      GROUP BY InvoiceID
  ) InvoiceItemSum ON InvoiceItemSum.InvoiceID = Invoice.InvoiceID
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT InvoiceID, SUM(PaymentAmount) AS SumOfPaymentAmount
    FROM Payment
    GROUP BY InvoiceID
  ) PaymentSum ON PaymentSum.InvoiceID = Invoice.InvoiceID
```

Comment: What happen if one of table don't have the records? like PaymentSum table have some records but InvoiceItemSum don't have any record, in this case excepted output should be some of values in PaymentSum table and 0 for InvoiceItemSum. will this query work in this scenario ?

Comment: @vijay.k I think the effect you want can be obtained using left join(s) rather than inner joins.

Comment: @Neil Thank you, and sorry for silly question.., what do you think about "CROSS APPLY" ? Please check my answer below and give your helpful suggestion.

Comment: @vijay.k Sorry I don't know about `CROSS APPLY`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    Invoice.InvoiceID,
    Invoice.`Date`,
    Invoice.Terms,
    Invoice.DateDue,
    Invoice.Status,
    Client.ClinicName,
    SUM(InvoiceItem.Amount),
    SUM(Payment.PaymentAmount)
FROM Invoice 
JOIN Client ON Client.ClientID=Invoice.ClientID
JOIN InvoiceItem ON InvoiceItem.InvoiceID=Invoice.InvoiceID
JOIN Payment ON Payment.InvoiceID=Invoice.InvoiceID
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6;
```

I did two things to your query:

1. Created separated joins for each of the child tables
2. Added a `group by`, without which the sum won't work correctly (fyi, in all other databases, omitting the group by would actually result in a syntax error)

Comment: i believe it's a typo error on this `OR Payment.InvoiceID=Invoice.InvoiceID` :)

Comment: what do you mean by this `group by 1,2,3,4,5,6` sir? :)

Comment: @JohnWoo That's SQL standard syntax for referring to grouped columns by column *position* rather than name. In this case it's equivalent to `group by Invoice.InvoiceID, Invoice.\`Date\`, Invoice.Terms, Invoice.DateDue, Invoice.Status, Client.ClinicName`. Some think it's blasphemy because "if you make a change to your selected columns your query might break". I prefer it because I find it more readable and I've been coding SQL for 20+ years and it's never caused me a single problem

Comment: great! Actually I never knew this until then :) thanks for the explaination. but that doesn't work on MSSQL ?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I am still having the same issue though with your solution. If I use only one SUM function (i.e. remove the Payment table), then it works just fine, but when I use two SUM functions from two different joined tables, the grouping does not seem to work.

Comment: I don't really get how this would solve the problem and why would you group by all columns???

Comment: @Bludream it isn't grouping over *all* the columns; it's grouping all the *non-aggregating* columns (the ones without `SUM()`). This query should work - what is it exactly you don't get?

Comment: @Bohemian, well I don't get the **Logic** and it didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Here try this one

```
SELECT  a.InvoiceID,
        a.`Date`,
        a.Terms,
        a.DateDue,
        a.Status,
        b.ClinicName,
        SUM(c.Amount),
        SUM(d.PaymentAmount)
FROM    Invoice a
            INNER JOIN Client b
                on a.ClientID = b.ClientID
            INNER JOIN InvoiceItem c
                ON c.InvoiceID = a.InvoiceID
            INNER JOIN JOIN Payment d
                ON d.InvoiceID = a.InvoiceID
GROUP BY    a.InvoiceID,
            a.`Date`,
            a.Terms,
            a.DateDue,
            a.Status,
            b.ClinicName
```

can you elaborate more on this?

> it is multiplying the SUM() by the number of records used to get the
>   sum (i.e. if there are two payments - 800,400 - It gives me
>   (800+400)*2 -- 2400)

Answer (score 0):

you can also achive it by "CROSS APPLY"

```
SELECT Invoice.InvoiceID, Invoice.`Date`, Invoice.Terms, Invoice.DateDue, Invoice.Status, Client.ClinicName, InvoiceItemSum.SumOfAmount, PaymentSum.SumOfPaymentAmount
  FROM Invoice
  INNER JOIN Client ON Client.ClientID = Invoice.ClientID
  CROSS APPLY ( SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Amount),0) AS SumOfAmount 
                                  FROM   InvoiceItem 
                                  WHERE  InvoiceID = Invoice.InvoiceID
                                ) InvoiceItemSum 
  CROSS APPLY ( SELECT ISNULL(SUM(PaymentAmount),0) AS SumOfPaymentAmount 
                                  FROM   Payment 
                                  WHERE  InvoiceID = Invoice.InvoiceID
                                ) PaymentSum
```

Comment: `CROSS APPLY` is an MS-SQL only extension.