# How to sumarize correctly as "Sickness time" from other table - mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime, difference

In mysql database i've created "Sickness" table:

```
    +--------+---------+---------+-------------+---------+-------------------------------+
    | Id_SICK|ID_WORKER| FNAME   | LNAME   | BEGIN_DATE          | END_DATE              |
    +--------+---------+---------+---------+------------+--------------------+-----------+
    | 4      |   26    | ANDREW  | WORM    |2019-03-19 07:00:00  |2019-03-19 15:00:00    |  
    +--------+---------+---------+----------------------+--------------------+-----------+  
    | 5      |   25    | ADAM    | GAX     |2019-03-21 07:00:00  |2019-03-21 15:00:00    |  
    +--------+---------+---------+----------------------+--------------------------------+
```

"Workers" table:

```
+--------+---------+---------+--
|ID_WORKER |  FNAME  | LNAME   |
+----------+---------+----------
| 25       |  ADAM   |  GAX    |
+----------+---------+----------
| 26       |  ANDREW |  WORM   |
+----------+---------+----------
```

"Orders" table:

```
+--------+---------+---------+------------+
|ID_ORDER  |  DESC_ORDER  | NUMBER_ORDER  |
+----------+---------+--------------------+
| 20       |  TEST        |  TEST         |
+----------+---------+--------------------+
```

And "Order_status" table:

```
+--------+---------+---------+---------+-------------+--------+----------+------------+
| Id_status|ID_WORKER| ID_ORDER| BEGIN_DATE          | END_DATE          | ORDER_DONE |
+----------+---------+---------+----------+------------+---------+--------------------+
| 47       |   25    |    20   |2019-03-18 06:50:35  |2019-03-18 15:21:32|  NO        |
+----------+---------+---------+------------+---------+-------------------+-----------+ 
| 48       |   25    |    20   |2019-03-20 06:44:12  |2019-03-20 15:11:23|  NO        |
+----------+---------+---------+------------+---------+-------------------+-----------+ 
| 50       |   25    |    20   |2019-03-22 06:50:20  |2019-03-22 12:22:33|  YES        |
+----------+---------+---------+------------+---------+-------------------+-----------+ 
| 51       |   26    |    20   |2019-03-18 06:45:11  |2019-03-18 15:14:45|  NO        |
+----------+---------+---------+------------+---------+-------------------+-----------+ 
| 52       |   26    |    20   |2019-03-20 06:50:22  |2019-03-20 15:10:32|  NO       |
+----------+---------+---------+------------+---------+-------------------+-----------+ 
| 53       |   25    |    20   |2019-03-22 06:54:11  |2019-03-22 11:23:45|  YES       |
+----------+---------+---------+------------+---------+-------------------+-----------+
```

I would like to sumarize "total time" of each other workers (in order_status table) on the order including with sumarizing "sickness time" from Sickness table. I have selected workers (LNAME, FNAME) orders (DESC_ORDER and NUMBER_ORDER) and "TOTAL TIME" on order from each other workers correctly. But i'm not able to sumarize sickness time. I wrote the mysql command in below:

```
SELECT workers.FNAME, workers.LNAME, orders.NUMBER_ORDER, orders.DESC_ORDER, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(order_status.END_DATE) - TIME_TO_SEC(order_status.BEGIN_DATE))) AS 'TOTAL TIME', SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(sickness.END_DATE) - TIME_TO_SEC(sickness.BEGIN_DATE))) AS 'SICKNESS TIME' FROM order_status INNER JOIN workers ON workers.ID_WORKER = order_status.ID_WORKER INNER JOIN orders ON orders.ID_ORDER = order_status.ID_ORDER INNER JOIN sickness ON sickness.ID_WORKER = workers.ID_WORKER WHERE orders.NUMBER_ORDER LIKE 'TEST' GROUP BY workers.ID_WORKER
```

Then i've got that result:

```
+--------+---------+---------+-------+------------+------------+-------------+
|  FNAME  | LNAME   |  NUMBER_ORDER  | DESC_ORDER | TOTAL TIME | SICKNESS_TIME|
+----------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+-------------+
|  ADAM   |  GAX    | TEST           | TEST       | 22:25:38   |   24:00:00   |
+----------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+-------------+
|  ANDREW |  WORM   | TEST           | TEST       | 22:52:12   |   24:00:00   |
+----------+---------+---------------+------------+------------+-------------+
```

As for as "Sickness time is incorrect" because from the "Sickness" after grouping ID_SICK is

```
+--------+---------+-----+
| Id_SICK| SICKNESS TIME |
+--------+---------+-----+
| 4      |   08:00:00    |  
+--------+---------+-----+ 
| 5      |   08:00:00    |   
+--------+---------+-----+
```

I have sumarize "TOTAL TIME + SICKNESS TIME" too for example

```
TOTAL TIME: 22:25:38 
SICKNESS TIME: 8:00:00

TOTAL + SICKNESS TIME : 22;25:38 + 8:00:00 = 30:25:38
```

Can someone please help me how to deal with? What kind of mysql query should i write? Any ideas? Thx for any help :)

Comment: In Sickness table example there is no id_worker column. Did you forget it?

Comment: eemmm. Yes. I forgot it, sorry for my mistake

Comment: Well, when you remember, update your question accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually expected. The above query is joining 4 tables:

- order_status
- sickness
- workers
- orders

"**workers**" table has a **1:N** relation to "**order_status**".

Also "**workers**" has **1:N** relation to sickness, actually it does not matter even if this is **1:1**.

The query is creating a Cartesian product between the above tables and **duplicate column values** from each table can be in the result set of the query above.

Remove the `group by` and the `sum` to see the result set.

eg in your example for id_worker 25, you have 3 order_status rows joined with 1 sickness row (this row values will be duplicated 3 times), joined with 1 workers row (again they will duplicated 3 times), joined with 1 orders row (same).

So the aggregate function `sum` combines duplicate values.

This would only work if result set contained unique rows for all columns used for aggregate functions

To solve this, use sub-queries to aggregate the results:

```
SELECT workers.fname, 
       workers.lname, 
       order_statusAgg.number_order,
       workers.id_worker,
       order_statusAgg.desc_order, 
       SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(order_statusAgg.stime)) AS 'TOTAL TIME', 
       SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(sicknessAgg.stime)) AS 'SICKNESS TIME' 
FROM   workers 
INNER JOIN (
SELECT sickness.id_worker, SUM((Time_to_sec(sickness.end_date) - 
                       Time_to_sec(sickness.begin_date))) AS stime
FROM sickness
GROUP BY sickness.id_worker
) sicknessAgg
               ON sicknessAgg.id_worker = workers.id_worker
       INNER JOIN (
SELECT order_status.id_worker, orders.number_order, orders.desc_order, SUM((Time_to_sec(order_status.end_date) - 
                       Time_to_sec(order_status.begin_date))) AS stime
FROM order_status
           INNER JOIN orders 
               ON orders.id_order = order_status.id_order
GROUP BY order_status.id_worker
) order_statusAgg
               ON workers.id_worker = order_statusAgg.id_worker 

WHERE  order_statusAgg.number_order LIKE 'TEST'
GROUP BY workers.id_worker
```

Note that in this case, it is needed to start from the **workers** table, as you want to aggregate a different number of rows from `order_status` and `sickness` tables.

References:

[How to join three tables to get Sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29879098/how-to-join-three-tables-to-get-sum)

[MySQL JOIN with multiple tables and SUMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12207200/mysql-join-with-multiple-tables-and-sums)

[How get the sum of two tables value using inner join](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/105062/how-get-the-sum-of-two-tables-value-using-inner-join)

Comment: Did you write in SQL or in MYSQL? Or wait... can You please tell me what are that codes about: `SUM(order_statusAgg.stime) AS 'TOTAL TIME' ` and  `order_statusAgg.number_order ` ?

Comment: Excuse me i rewrote this code from you but it shows only in seconds not in time how to change result from seconds to time? I'm trying to solve it.

Comment: @Prochu1991 I updated the code to show in time instead of seconds.

Comment: thank you for answer but i can't still find solution about 'Sickness Time' becasue each other worker got only one day of sickness (8:00:00 Hours in time) so for each worker should be about  `Sickness time = 8:00:00` for `ID_WORKER= 25` and  `ID_WORKER= 26` too. Not  `Sickness time = 22:13:20` for  `ID_WORKER= 25` and `ID_WORKER= 26`.

Comment: @Prochu1991 You are right, I forgot to use SUM in the subqueries. corrected

Comment: Now all of them is correct. I've really said "I'm not SQL guru" Thank you very much for big help! :)